# My mobile part of ExtLib in XPages not working

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

Have problem with mobile part of ExtLib. I now reinstalled all to latest server 9.0.1 and do my first test. 
ALl other ExtLib function work, in which case the features I tested. Have also tried ExtLib application and where it works as it should except Mobile.

If I use the solutions for mobile that I built in the past they do not work or if I build new. XPages/ExtLib/Mobile shows a blank page and no errors but if I check in the code, the following message.

Same error regardless of application, feels like something is missing. I have also installed the latest version from OpenNTF but the error persists.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

XSP.addOnLoad(function() {XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:appPage3_content:_id9","view:_id1:appPage3_content:button2","view:_id1:appPage3_content", "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:appPage3_content");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:appPage3_content:_id10", "view:_id1:appPage3_content:tabBarButtonCancel", "view:_id1:appPage3_content", "onclick", function(){}, 0, "view:_id1:appPage3_content");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:appPage3_content:_id12", "view:_id1:appPage3_content:tabBarButtonSave", "view:_id1:appPage3_content", "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:appPage3_content");
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage3_content:inputTextSubject",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage3_content:inputTextCategory1",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage3_content:inputText2",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:appPage4_content:_id31", "view:_id1:appPage4_content:saveButtoninActionFacet", "view:_id1:appPage4_content", "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:appPage4_content");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:appPage4_content:_id32", "view:_id1:appPage4_content:tabBarButtonSubmit", "view:_id1:appPage4_content", "onClick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:appPage4_content");
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage4_content:inputTextSubject2",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage4_content:inputTextCategory2",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
XSP.attachValidator("view:_id1:appPage4_content:inputText1",new XSP.RequiredValidator("Validation Error: Value is required."),null);
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: The mobile controls changed significantly between 8.5.2 and 8.5.3. You may need to replace the structural components with equivalents that are valid for the new version.

Comment: I built them in 8.5.3 and even built a new one in 9.0.1. Same error

Comment: What is the error? I'm not seeing any error message in your question.

Comment: Its strange, i could seethat dataview find the document beacuse i could scroll down. But its not display the content, buttons, topbar. The page is just blank. If i view source i could read that you see over in the end of the xpage

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue or not, but in the Xsp Properties on the General tab. Ensure the "Use mobile theme for XPages with the prefix:" is checked and then define a mobile prefix (i.e. "m_"). Then your xpage should be named "**m_**something". Also ensure the "Mobile theme" is set to "Mobile default".

The code you pasted into your question isn't reporting an error but is defining the client side events on your xpage.